# the change of storage trie tree when the data in smart contract is changed

Tags: solidity, merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, storage-trie

As we all know,the data in smart contract is stored in storage trie tree. If the data of a smart contract is modified, will a new storage trie tree be generated, or will the data is modified on the original storage trie tree?

I want to know what happend to storage trie tree when the data in smart contract is changed.

Hope you can give me some help!